# XML dynamic SiteMap asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sitemap

I tried to make dynamic Site Map using Asp.net. I'm using XML file to write in which is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset>
</urlset>
```

and code behind for Article.aspx which have urls

```
string xmlpath = @"~/data.xml";
var path = Server.MapPath(xmlpath);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
XElement root = new XElement("url");
root.Add(new XElement("loc", url));
root.Add(new XElement("lastmod", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMdd")));
root.Add(new XElement("lastmod", "daily"));
root.Add(new XElement("priority", "1.0"));
doc.Element("urlset").Add(root);
doc.Save(path);
```

This code is working good and I get the XML file correctly the problem is Google Search console need me to add xmlns nameSpace to the urlset element so it must be like this:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
</urlset>
```

When I do add the NameSpace xmlns to the the `<urlset>` tag I get this error:

> object reference not set

Comment: Read up on how to use [`XName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xname) to work with namespaces in LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer as "madreflection" mentioned at Microsoft community
code behind:

```
   XNamespace aw = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
    doc.Element(aw + "urlset").Add(root);
```

and my XML file is

```
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
  </url>
  </urlset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like creating a new XDocument by parsing a string especially when you have namespaces

```
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                         "<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">" +
                         "</urlset>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement urlset = doc.Root;
```